# Белые границы у Canvas в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, border, frame

Помогите пожалуйста. Начал практиковаться в tkinter, столкнулся с одной проблемой, а именно: белые границы у элемента. Прикладываю фото. Задний фон задан, а рамка вокруг элемента всё равно сохраняется белым цветом - из-за чего портится весь внешний вид. Не могу понять, каким образом её можно убрать.
Подскажите, куда копать?
Код элемента:

```
def Lines():
        canvas = Canvas(bg='#DDDDDD')
        canvas.create_line(354, 100, 20, 100, width=3)
        canvas.create_line(354, 200, 20, 200, width=3)
        canvas.create_line(130, 300, 130, 0, width=3)
        canvas.create_line(243, 300, 243, 0, width=3)
        canvas.place(x=20, y=80, width=406, height=400)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать `highlightthickness` установить в значение **0**

> `highlightthickness` - устанавливает толщину границы виджета.

```
from tkinter import *

def Lines():
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, bg='#DDDDDD', highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.create_line(354, 100, 20, 100, width=3)
    canvas.create_line(354, 200, 20, 200, width=3)
    canvas.create_line(130, 300, 130, 0, width=3)
    canvas.create_line(243, 300, 243, 0, width=3)
    canvas.place(x=20, y=80, width=406, height=400)
    root.mainloop()

Lines()
```

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо, Вы решили мою проблему =)